# Having issues with making openvpn connection

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn, openvpn

I am trying to use **Open VPN** to connect to a network, but getting this output after I click connect and enter username and password:

```
Fri Mar 20 17:00:06 2020 OpenVPN 2.4.8 x86_64-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [PKCS11] [AEAD] built on Oct 31 2019
Fri Mar 20 17:00:06 2020 Windows version 6.1 (Windows 7) 64bit
Fri Mar 20 17:00:06 2020 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.0l  10 Sep 2019, LZO 2.10
Enter Management Password:
Fri Mar 20 17:00:09 2020 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]someIP.xx.xx.xx:2195
Fri Mar 20 17:00:09 2020 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]someIP.xx.xx.xx:2195 [nonblock]
Fri Mar 20 17:00:10 2020 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]someIP.xx.xx.xx:2195
Fri Mar 20 17:00:10 2020 TCP_CLIENT link local: (not bound)
Fri Mar 20 17:00:10 2020 TCP_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]someIP.xx.xx.xx:2195
Fri Mar 20 17:00:10 2020 Connection reset, restarting [0]
Fri Mar 20 17:00:10 2020 SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, process restarting
Fri Mar 20 17:00:15 2020 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]someIP.xx.xx.xx:2195
Fri Mar 20 17:00:15 2020 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]someIP.xx.xx.xx:2195 [nonblock]
Fri Mar 20 17:00:16 2020 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]someIP.xx.xx.xx:2195
Fri Mar 20 17:00:16 2020 TCP_CLIENT link local: (not bound)
Fri Mar 20 17:00:16 2020 TCP_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]someIP.xx.xx.xx:2195
Fri Mar 20 17:00:16 2020 Connection reset, restarting [0]
Fri Mar 20 17:00:16 2020 SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, process restarting
Fri Mar 20 17:00:21 2020 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]someIP.xx.xx.xx:2195
Fri Mar 20 17:00:21 2020 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]someIP.xx.xx.xx:2195 [nonblock]
Fri Mar 20 17:00:22 2020 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]someIP.xx.xx.xx:2195
Fri Mar 20 17:00:22 2020 TCP_CLIENT link local: (not bound)
Fri Mar 20 17:00:22 2020 TCP_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]someIP.xx.xx.xx:2195
Fri Mar 20 17:00:22 2020 Connection reset, restarting [0]
Fri Mar 20 17:00:22 2020 SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, process restarting
Fri Mar 20 17:00:27 2020 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]someIP.xx.xx.xx:2195
Fri Mar 20 17:00:27 2020 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]someIP.xx.xx.xx:2195 [nonblock]
Fri Mar 20 17:00:28 2020 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]someIP.xx.xx.xx:2195
Fri Mar 20 17:00:28 2020 TCP_CLIENT link local: (not bound)
Fri Mar 20 17:00:28 2020 TCP_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]someIP.xx.xx.xx:2195
Fri Mar 20 17:00:28 2020 Connection reset, restarting [0]
Fri Mar 20 17:00:28 2020 SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, process restarting
Fri Mar 20 17:00:33 2020 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]someIP.xx.xx.xx:2195
Fri Mar 20 17:00:33 2020 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]someIP.xx.xx.xx:2195 [nonblock]
Fri Mar 20 17:00:34 2020 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]someIP.xx.xx.xx:2195
Fri Mar 20 17:00:34 2020 TCP_CLIENT link local: (not bound)
Fri Mar 20 17:00:34 2020 TCP_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]someIP.xx.xx.xx:2195
Fri Mar 20 17:00:34 2020 Connection reset, restarting [0]
Fri Mar 20 17:00:34 2020 SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, process restarting
Fri Mar 20 17:00:35 2020 SIGTERM[hard,init_instance] received, process exiting
```

Does anyone at least have some idea what can be causing this?

This is config:

```
dev tun
persist-tun
persist-key
cipher AES-256-CBC
ncp-ciphers AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM:AES-256-CBC
auth SHA1
tls-client
client
resolv-retry infinite
remote server.gol.ge 2195 tcp-client
verify-x509-name "ServerOpenVPN" name
auth-user-pass
remote-cert-tls server
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the server, post the server logs. Could be the server that is disconnecting you.

One thing: check firewall settings at either side. Client-side, you may have to adjust the Windows firewall or your antivirus suite. Perhaps disable it and see if the connection succeeds and remains stable. Then you'll know if this is the cause of the problem.